# Klein-Gordon field operators in the Schrodinger and Heisenberg pictures

Tags: quantum-field-theory, klein-gordon-equation

In the Heisenberg picture we have (given by 2.25 using Peskin and Schoroeder's book):
$$
\phi(\vec{x}) \propto a_p e^{i px} + a_p^{\dagger} e^{-ipx}
$$
while in the Schrodinger picture (equation 2.47):
$$
\phi(\vec{x},t) \propto a_p e^{-i px} + a_p^{\dagger} e^{ipx}|_{p^0 = E_p}.
$$

I am not able to understand the difference in these two equations. Why in one picture we are creating particles with positive momenta (the first equation) while in the second we create particles with negative momenta (actually energy) (and the inverse interpretation for the other operator, we destroy particles with negative momenta (energy) in the first and with positive in the latter).

Do we have a typo in the last equation and we should have "t"instead of "x"? If not, where is the time-dependence in the operator?

Comment: In the first equation, the exponent is $e^{ i \vec{p} \cdot \vec{x}}$ whereas in the second line the exponent is $e^{ - i p \cdot x } = e^{ i p^0 t + i \vec{p} \cdot \vec{x} }$. Also, I'm pretty sure you have mixed up Heisenberg and Schrodinger pictures. Operators have NO time dependence in the latter.

Comment: @Prahar, please remember P&S' Lorentz signature  +--- on their p. xix: $e^{-ip\cdot x}=e^{-ip^0t+i\mathbf{p\cdot x}}.$

Comment: @KurtG. - You are right. I did screw up the metric signature there. I meant $e^{- i p \cdot x } = e^{ - i p^0 t + i \vec{p} \cdot \vec{x} }$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The P&S formulas read
$$
\phi(\mathbf{x}) =\int \frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^3}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\omega_\mathbf{p}}} a_\mathbf{p} e^{i \mathbf{p\cdot x}} + a_\mathbf{p}^{\dagger} e^{-i\mathbf{p\cdot x}}
$$
and
$$
\phi(\mathbf{x},t)=\int \frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^3}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2E_\mathbf{p}}}  a_\mathbf{p} e^{-i {p\cdot x}} + a_\mathbf{p}^{\dagger} e^{i{p\cdot x}}\Bigg|_{p^0=E_\mathbf{p}}\,.
$$
In P&S, bold symbols represent three-vectors while non bold symbols represent four vectors **and** there is a Lorentz signature $+---$ in the "four-scalar product":
$$
\mathbf{p\cdot x}=p^1x^1+p^2x^2+p^3x^3 ,\quad p\cdot x=p^0x^0-p^1x^1-p^2x^2-p^3x^3\,.
$$
Because $x^0$ is time, we see now that $\phi(\mathbf{x})$ has no time dependence while $\phi(\mathbf{x},t)$ has.