# A sign issue with the Klein-Gordon propagator

Tags: quantum-field-theory, conventions, fourier-transform, propagator, klein-gordon-equation

I am trying to evaluate
$$
D(x-y) = \langle0| \phi(x) \phi(y) |0\rangle
$$
for the Klein-Gordon field. What I tried so far:

$$
=\langle0| \int \frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^3} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2E_p}} (a_p e^{ipx} + a_p^{\dagger} e^{-ipx}) \int \frac{d^3q}{(2\pi)^3} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2E_q}} (a_q e^{iqy} + a_p^{\dagger} e^{-iqy})|0\rangle
$$
the only term that survives is:
$$
=\langle0| \int \frac{d^3p d^3q}{(2\pi)^6} \frac{1}{2\sqrt{E_p E_q}} (a_p a_q^{\dagger} e^{ipx}e^{-iqy}) |0\rangle
$$
and we can write the operators in term of the fundamental commutators as:
$$
=\langle0| \int \frac{d^3p d^3q}{(2\pi)^6} \frac{1}{2\sqrt{E_p E_q}} ([a_p,a_q^{\dagger}] + a_q^{\dagger}a_p) e^{ipx}e^{-iqy} |0\rangle
$$
where the second term vanishes and, therefore:
$$
=\langle0| \int \frac{d^3p d^3q}{(2\pi)^6} \frac{1}{2\sqrt{E_p E_q}} (2\pi)^3 \delta(p-q) e^{ipx}e^{-iqy} |0\rangle
$$
we integrate the dirac function:
$$
=\langle0| \int \frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^3} \frac{1}{2 E_p} e^{ip(x-y)} |0\rangle.
$$

And this differ from Peskin-Schroeder's book equation (2.50) by a simple negative sign in the exponent (it should be $-ip(x-y)$) and both bra and ket vanished as well. I do think that the sign should be a minor mistake that I cannot see. But I have no idea what happened with the vacuum eigenstates.

Comment: My gosh, of course the $\langle 0 |0 \rangle$ comes from the normalization of the eigenstates. But still a bit unsure on the minus sign issue.

Comment: @Edison: Please digest my answer to [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/651054/) first.

Comment: Hint: Change integration variable $\vec{p}\to-\vec{p}$.

Comment: Your starting point is wrong! It should be $a_{\bf p} e^{- i p \cdot x}$. Look at (2.47) in P&S.